# Is it safe to recharge a battery without a specific device?

Tags: batteries

I have 9V Li-ion battery. If I apply regulated 9V to it, will it recharge?
What about other kinds of rechargeable batteries?

Comment: http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/lithium_ion_safety_concerns http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_lithium_ion_batteries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the graph at endolith's link: http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_lithium_ion_batteries

You don't need an official charger, but a constant voltage isn't what you need either.  You need a constant current, followed by a constant voltage, followed by switching off the charging circuit.  I have used a standard adjustable-current bench supply for this.  It works fine if the current and voltage limits are set appropriately.  (For safety's sake, don't charge the battery all the way.  If it starts to feel warm, shut off the charger.)

Comment: Max safe temp when charging is about 45°C. It should be fine if it goes over it, but I wouldn't risk it.

Comment: Name of the standard adjustable-current bench supply you used? or much better: name of an integrated circuit for doing that? thanks

Answer (score 5):

No, it is definitely not safe.

The Li batteries and compatible chargers usually mate with more than just 2 wires. The battery must include termoswitch or thermometer circuit which is servo feedback to charger controller. The constant parameter of control loop is not a voltage or current, but top temperature over time figure to avoid fire damage.

Comment: Actually you're wrong. Li-Ion shouldn't heat up much when charged. Also those extra wires are breakout connectors for each individual cell so each cells voltage can be measured and so that that it's possible to do cell balancing. Inbuilt circuit is there as a safeguard so you can't draw too much current and over-charge/discharge the battery pack. It also includes temperature safeguard, but the funny thing is that heat generated by the cell when charged is insignificant compared to heat generated resistive elements on the circuit. If you charge it with 0.8C it should be fine.

Comment: Yes. They should. But "heat much" or "heat less" is subjective thing, depending on legal environment for particular geographies and engineering/consumer cultures

Answer (score 2):

Yeah. It'll recharge for a few seconds. But then it explodes, bummer. Battery chargers exist for good reason.

Comment: It can only explode when exposed to high temperatures, the integrated safeguard circuit shouldn't let you to do that via charging unless you do something horribly wrong.